# Text component value not changing in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component in which the value of the Text component is not being updated, even though updates are being showed in the `Render()` function.

The component is nested like so:

```
render() {
    const myValue = this.state.myValue
    console.warn('Value: ' + myValue)
    return <View>
        ...
        <View>
             <Image>
                 <Text>{myValue}</Text>
             </Image>
        </View>
        ....
    </View>
}
```

The problem is that the `console.warn` is showing the value is changing and the constant value is being set. However the `<Text>` component itself is not updating. The `<Text>` component is wrapped in an `<Image>` component as it's the background image for this section. The `Render()` method is called four times a second in my case as we have a timer bar that's constantly receiving updates.

Why would the `<Text>` component not be getting updated as expected?

**NOTE:** The `<Text>` component updates if I change the `<Image>` component to a `<View>` but a background image is necessary for this section.

Comment: Have you tried add the background image to the view? I cannot see a way how the text will work inside a image.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working?  I've just tested it with a button that increment myValue with each click and it works. See the gist (there's a GIF in the bottom of the page) https://gist.github.com/cdes/cc6605f390915b1c8e21f8030692786e

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad - I'm absolutely sure, I had to go as far as bringing the text outside of the `<Image>` component and give it an `absolute` position on top of the image for it to receive updates.

Comment: @Hobbyist How are you updating state?

Comment: @Hobbyist If you are updating the const, it will not trigger a rerender because state has not been changed. To trigger a rerender, you have to use this.setState().

Comment: @AhmedAlHaddad The constant value is pulled from the state, so if the constant value is changed when render() is called, the value in state was changed. Render() is only called if the state is changed, props are received, or under a few special conditions,.

Answer (score 0):

When using `const` it says to `React` that the pointer didn't change and the render will do nothing.

Try to connect it directlly to the state, like this:

```
render() {
    console.warn('Value: ' + this.state.myValue)
    return <View>
        ...
        <View>
             <Image>
                 <Text>{this.state.myValue}</Text>
             </Image>
        </View>
        ....
    </View>
}
```

Comment: I moved things around from my work-around to try this, nothing happened. Also, I use const all the time with the deconstruction operator: IE: `const { x, y } = this.props` which is shown in the React documentation as-well. I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What I think causes the issue, is that the Image component becomes cached and the call to `this.setState({myValue: 'text'})` misses the action to refresh the image and all the containing components, in this case your Text component. A call to `this.forceUpdate()` after the call to `setState()` worked for me.

Also, not sure what version of React you were using, but you can also see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47440583/5889360) about putting other components inside an ImageComponent in react-native.