# The <Image> component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am completing a tutorial on react native.  For a certain screen, the instructor recommends the following code:

```
<Image source={bgImage} style={styles.backgroundContainer}> 
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Quote quoteText={this.props.text} quoteSource={this.props.source}/>
    </View>
</Image>
```

But when I use this, I get the above error.

I've tried alternatives to this, but when I do, the background image doesn't even load.

**EDIT:** As requested below, here's my styling code.  What I'm going for is using a background gradient image stored locally to the app code with text overlayed over that background.  What I currently get by using the suggestion below is just the text at the very top of the screen and no background image.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    backgroundColor: '#889DAD',
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not allowed to put other components inside an image component. You need to wrap a View around your Image and positioned it as absolute.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1}}>
<Image source={bgImage} style={styles.backgroundContainer} /> 
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Quote quoteText={this.props.text} quoteSource={this.props.source}/>
</View>
</View>


container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0, 
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
```

**EDIT:**
Since react-native version 50.0, you can simply use [ImageBackground](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting)

Comment: That's what I tried at first.  However when I did that, the image didn't render (which may be a completely different issue altogether, I'll admit).

Comment: I edited the OP to include the styling objective and the styling code I used.

Comment: Yes, removing the styling of "backgroundContainer" make the background image render properly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

Since react-native 0.50 you can't nest components inside `<Image>` tag, rather you have to use [`<ImageBackground>`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting) for background images. [Release Notes for v0.50.0](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.50.0)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<ImageBackground
    source={image}
    style={styles.contentContainer} >
    // Your view content goes here

 </ImageBackground>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    contentContainer: {
        flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Works like a charm