# How to put image background in React native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to a background in my react native app and this is my code.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View 
         style={{
             alignItems: 'center',
             flex:1}}>
        <Image 
           source={darkwallpaper} 
           style={{
             flex: 1, 
             width: '100%'}}/> 
        <View  
           style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center'}}>
          <ScrollView>
             <Text>This is the random Top page</Text>
             <Image 
                source={homemoviespic} 
                style={{width: '100%'}}/>
             <TopMovies />
         </ScrollView>
       </View>
      )
    }
```

Right now, the background shows but the scrollview is not working. I cant scroll and I can see only a few parts of the stuff inside scrollview. Please help.

Comment: remove justifyContent and alignItems from scrollview's parent

Comment: And only have position absolute? I tried it and it still doesnt scroll.

Comment: Found something called ImageBackground that can put image in background and you can just put children in the tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47439627/the-image-component-cannot-contain-children-if-you-want-to-render-content-on/47442746#47442746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something called ImageBackground that can put image in background and you can just put children in the tag.

Answer (score 1):

`<Image>` with nested content is no longer supported. Use `<ImageBackground>` instead.

```
<ImageBackground style={styles} source={source} resizeMode={resizeMode} >
  {children}
</ImageBackground>
```